# android code to launch my app as soon as phone bootsup

Tags: android

Hi can anybody give me sample code for launching application as soon as phone boots up

Answer (score 5):

you need a `BroadcastReceiver` like this

```
public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(YourClass)
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

also this user permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and the recever in your  tag in the manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```